# How can I remove a magnet stuck to a metal bar (under my table)?

Tags: metals, magnetism

I have this strong rectangular permanent magnet that got stuck to a metal bar. My living room table has a sliding top and the metal bar is part of the mechanism that the top slides on.

The magnet looks as shown:

[image]

The magnet is in a slightly awkward place but some of the things I have thought of is to perhaps place another magnet on the opposite side of the metal bar in such a way that it pushes this stuck magnet away from the bar.

I do have a bunch of other magnets I could try for this but I would probably have to arrange them in some way to make them stronger. Or alternatively this idea is just a pipe dream.

I have not been able to pull either end of the magnet from the bar even a millimeter as of yet.

What things could I try to remove the magnet from the metal bar?

Comment: Metals use their magnetic properties when heated, so I'm guessing a hairdryer (or a blowtorch, if you're feeling adventurous) could be of help. Can you remove the bar from the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though the magnet is stuck to a raised black metal piece, and "above" it is non-magnetic wood. My solution is to slide one end of the magnet "up", so it sticks out over the wood area. Once that tip is sticking out, you should be able to grab it with your fingers (or pliers) and lift it off the metal.

It will be even easier if you can prevent the other end from sliding farther down the black metal. You can do this by wedging something non-metallic in between that end of the magnet and the "lower" edge of the black metal.

[image]

Comment: Using a flathead screwdriver could help you get it over that lip in the first place. Leverage!

Answer (score 1):

Use a c clamp and tighten it around the magnet. Now you have good grip you can pull the clamp with great force finally take apart the magnet

Answer (score 0):

You could try to demagnetize the magnet.  Here's an article on how to do that: [How do I demagnetize something?](https://www.reference.com/science/demagnetize-something-9302de807860aec1)